# Why Yolo_9000 use only local image information?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

One thing confused me when I was reading the Yolo_9000 paper.
In Yolov2 structure, the final layer size is 13x13, seems each cell contains roughly 32x32 image information from original image. For me, it looks like to use only local information to fit a object detection, I am not sure whether it is enough or robust.

In v1 version, there is a full connected layer to combine local to global information, I feel that  is more reasonable.

Or something I understand wrong, this question does bother me.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

But the information is already used by the convolutions. Every 3x3 filter uses the sorrounding information of the last filter at every pixel. Those pixels are in turn already convolutions and use the surrounding information of their pixels and so on and so forth. In combination with reduction in the image size by max pooling the whole image is covered like this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, the window go through whole image, but each window only lead on one pixel(with new depth) in the next layer. For example, input is 32x32x3, I use 3x3 with depth 16 convol layer, it's result is 32x32x16. each 3x3 filter only gather information around. The depth 16 is only feature dimension. Another thing I can take the convolution layer as 16xSobel detector, there is no global information using soble canny edge detection.

Comment: Yes a sobel is only local information, but with the next sobel filter the reach increases and if you add enough sobel filters you will have incorparated global information into every pixel. E.g. if you use a 3x3 sobel filter you have in this specific pixel incorparated the information of the sourrounding pixel. Then if you use another 3x3 sobel filter you will have the information incorporated of the nearby pixel which already have the neighboorhood pixel incorporated which can also be archived by a bigger filter kernel. This effect is amplified by the pooling operation.

Comment: Thanks. That's reasonable. Another question it seem requires enough layers to get global information, the depth filters in one layer won't add larger neighbor area information considering they are same size and work on the output from layer before.

Comment: Just to make sure. Thank you for your response. Thank you.